# get <Title>, <Description> and Status code for a lot of URLs

Tags: c#, .net

I have a big list that contains urls (List urlList). The goal is to get these three infomation (tag `<title>`, tag `<description>` and status code) for each url in the big list. Notice that It's a very big list of URLs, they may contain the same host.

I've tried using HttpWebRequest, something like below:

```
request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
request.UserAgent = "html-analyzor";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 20000;

this._Response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

// Get title, description, statuscode ...
...
```

It's working, but not really well...
I don't know if it's related to the amount of requests it has to make, but i got sometimes errors (404, 5XX, operation has timed out...) from some of the urls (not always the same urls)

Can you guys help me please?

Regards,

Comment: What is your question about? HttpWebRequest (and the errors you get sometimes)? or parsing the returned content?

Comment: How big is _very big_? How many requests do you send simultaneously?

Comment: @Eser: My question is: is there a more stable way to make a lot of requests in order  to retrieve information such as tags and status code?

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus: I should say, it contains 7K-10K urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are going through a list of URLs, accessing each URL storing the results of each request. You say your code works but `not very well`. Actually, it is behaving exactly as I would expect because:

- 10k URLs is quite a few. Assuming that 90% succeed you will experience 1000 failures which will all hamper your strategy. See the following bullets for details:
- Not all requests from a large URL list will be valid (error 404)
- You will not have access (authorization) to all URLs (error 5xx)
- Your timeout is very long at 20 seconds. Some requests may take up all that time before timing out (failing) slowing down your application significantly. Create a shorter timeout and also make that value configurable
- You do not seem to be using threads. This is a perfect place to use threading and spread the workload. It really depends on your definition of `very long list`. If there are enough URLs you might even consider running this from several separate machines
- You should understand that making these calls puts extra pressure on the target server and your machine and network as well. This extra use of resources will slow things down and make timeouts more likely.

Comment: @Leona It can be quite common to get a sporadic 404 or a 500 when automatically accessing a long list of sites.  This can be due to connectivity issues on your or their end, or anywhere in between.  Sites are also taken down periodically for maintenance or due to other issues.  You should anticipate this behaviour and adapt to it

Comment: @PaulSasik: Thanks for your answer. But this program is meant to analyse these urls, if i got a 404 or a 5xx for a url who is in fact working, it means the program gives wrong information. no?

Comment: @Leona: No. Martin is right, see his comment above, that web servers do not always behave in a stable manner. An otherwise well-functioning web server might bog down during prime use or other heavy load situations and time out. Also, I don't know what your URLs look like. In many situations you might be able to access the main page of a site but requesting any other resource might require authentication which would give you a 5xx error.

Comment: @MartinParkin - It's true that sporadic timeouts will likely increase if you start making a lot of web requests from a single machine but if you get a 404 or 5xx it means that you reached the web server and it's responding with a very particular error message. Yes, the server may be under load and start dropping requests but I would not expect resource or auth-specific errors in that case. (Unless it's a crappy, buggy web server.)

Comment: @Leona: One more thing. These failures you're seeing are just part of what happens when web requests are made. i.e. Sometimes a web request will fail for seemingly no reason at all. At this point it becomes a business issue: What does it mean to analyze a response when an error can happen arbitrarily? How do you mitigate these errors? (Running the analysis at 2 am perhaps?) How do errors inform your analysis? etc.

Comment: @PaulSasik,@Martin, Thanks a lot for your answers and patience :)